# GeoIP doesn't work

Tags: vidalia

When I open Network Map, all of the country flags show up as null, and the map is unannotated.

[image: screenshot]

It's a fresh installation of Vidalia Relay Bundle, and `geoIP` is in `AppData\Local\Vidalia`, `AppData\Local\Tor\`, as well as `AppData\Roaming\tor\geoip`.

I also want geoIP, for example, to restrict exit locations.

**How do I make exit geoIP identification work?**

Answer (score 2):

[geoip.vidalia-project.net has been shut down.](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/shutting-down-vidalia-geoip-mapping-server)